# Ruby Socket Inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, sockets

I'm writing a Ruby class that extends `TCPSocket`. Assume it looks something like this:

```
class FooSocket < TCPSocket
    def hello
        puts 'hello'
    end
end
```

I have a `TCPServer` listening for incoming connections

```
server = TCPServer.new 1234
socket = server.accept
```

When my server finally accepts a connection, it will return a `TCPSocket`. However, I want a `FooSocket` so that I can call `socket.hello`.

How can I change `TCPSocket` into a `FooSocket`?

I could duck-punch the methods and attributes I want directly onto the `TCPSocket` class, but I'm using it elsewhere and so I don't want to do that.

Probably the easiest solution is to write a class that encapsulates a `TCPSocket`, and just pass the socket returned by `accept` as a param. However, I'm interested to know how to do it through inheritance—I've been trying to bend my mind around it but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do that would be to make `FooSocket` a module, and then `extend` it into your `TCPSocket`s that need the special methods. Here are some examples of how this could be used:

```
module FooSocket
  def hello
    self.puts 'hello' # could also be written without the 'self',
  end                 # but it is clearer this way because it may
end                   # be mistaken for the Kernel method.

server = TCPServer.new 1234
socket = server.accept.extend FooSocket
```

You could also easily override `TCPServer` to return one of these:

```
class TCPServer
  alias old_accept accept
  def accept
    old_accept.extend FooSocket
  end
end
```

If you didn't want to override standard classes, you could define a singleton class on your server (which is what I would do) because you will most likely only have one server. To do this, replace the line `class TCPServer` in the above example with `class << server`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override `accept` in the `TCPServer` class to return a `FooSocket` instead of a `TCPSocket`, either via reopening the class, or subclassing and using that. Your idea of dressing up an instance of `TCPSocket` after it's been returned by `accept` is cleaner I think.